# What does a 2 byte hexadecimal value look like?

Tags: binary, hex, decimal

I'm trying to understand what a two byte hexadecimal value would look like. As an example, we have the decimal values **41** and **-73** with their two-byte binary equivalents:

dec

**41** -binary: 000000 00101001

**-73** -binary: 11111111 10110111

The hex should then be **29**(base16) and **49**(base16) respectively. How are these hex values represented in a "two byte" value. Am I doing something wrong here?

thanks

Comment: For the -73, you would need to do a sign extension to get `11111111 10110111` in binary. 41 in hex would be `0x0029` and -73 would be `0xFFB7`. `0x0049` would be +73.

Comment: Ahh that's exaclty the answer. Thank you!

Comment: For -73 -> signed hex, why is the last value 7? I thought you did `15-number` to get complements? If you subtract 15 from every value it should be `0xFFB6`?

Comment: That would be `16-number`. Personally I find the easiest way to perform 2's complement is by flipping all the bits and adding one. That way a +73  `0000 0000  0100 1001` would become a -73 like so: `1111 1111 1011 0110+1`. You can then see, looking at the groups of 4 bits, we get `F F B 7`.